# Print SQL values in Android studio Java

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make a function that when you open the app the first thing it does it checks with a query if there are any null values in SQL the code is this:

```
public static String checkParameters(Context ctx) {        
    Parameters prm = new Parameters(ctx);
    SQLiteDatabase db = prm.getWritableDatabase();
    String count = "select * from table paramname where paramvalue=''";
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(count, null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    int icount = c.getInt(0);
    if(icount > 0){
        "Success";
    }else{
        "Error";
    }
    return null;
}
```

But this isn't working I need to make the function check which paramname has paramvalue empty and print that paramname.

Comment: Please add sample data for your table, and also tell us what the actual table name is.

Comment: the tables name is parameters and the data is like paramname="OWNER" paramvalue="JOHN" now can be case that paramvalue can be empty on the OWNER row so the code must detect it. That query does this specific thing because i tested it on sql

Answer (score 0):

I sense that your bigger problem is on the SQL side, so here is a query you can use to detect what you want:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN paramname = 'OWNER' AND paramvalue IS NOT NULL
                  THEN 1 END) AS flag;
```

This will return a single record result set, with the value being 1 when OWNER has a non null value.  Note that I am assuming that an empty parameter value is represented by NULL, and not empty string.  It should be represented by NULL.

Sample Android code:

```java
String sql = "SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN paramname = 'OWNER' AND ";
sql += "                             paramvalue IS NOT NULL " +
sql += "                        THEN 1 END) AS flag";
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
int cnt = 0;
if (c.moveToFirst()) {
    cnt = c.getInt(0);
}

if (cnt > 0) {
    // success
}
else {
    // failure
}
```

Comment: the query works because there are 14 values total in paramname and paramvalue

Comment: What i want now is how to print the sql value that is returned

Comment: I have given you a skeleton Java code you may use in your app.

Comment: Yes this is okay but how can i print the paramname that has the paramvalue null

Comment: You just changed your question.  The original question was about detecting whether the OWNER parameter has a missing value.  You may want to ask a new question.